# Get substring until first numeric character

Tags: vb.net

like my title already explained, I want to get a substring of a string (who contains a address) and I would like to have only the street..

It's not possible to only take the text (non-numeric) chars, because then the box will remain.
It's not possible to take substring till first space, because the streetname can contain a space..

For example 'developerstreet 123a' -> would like to have 'developerstreet'
The 'a' is a box number of the house, which I'm not interested in..

How can I do this in VB.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing addresses is notoriously difficult, so I caution you to make sure that you a very deliberate about the choices you make.  I would strongly recommend reviewing the documentation provided by the postal service.  If these are US addresses, you should start by looking at the [USPS Publication 28](http://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/welcome.htm).

However, to answer your specific question, you can find the index of the first numeric character in a string by using the [`Char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char.IsDigit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.  You may also want to take a look at the [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isnumber%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, but that's probably more inclusive than what you really want.  For instance, this will get the index of the first numeric character in the `input` string:

```
Dim index As Integer = -1
For i As Integer = 0 to input.Length - 1
    If Char.IsDigit(input(i)) Then
        index = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

However, for complex string parsing, like this, I would suggest learning *Regular Expressions*.  Getting the non-numeric portion at the beginning of a string becomes trivial with [`RegEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, "^\D+")
If m.Success Then
    Dim nonNumericPart As String = m.Value
End If
```

Here is the meaning of the regular expression in the above example:

- `^` - The matching string must start at the beginning of the line
- `\D` - Any non-numeric character
- `+` - One or more times

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    Private Sub MyFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

     Dim str As String = "developerstreet 123a"
            Dim index As Integer = GetIndexOfNumber(str)
            Dim substr As String = str.Substring(0, index)
            MsgBox(substr)
    End Sub



       Public Function GetIndexOfNumber(ByVal str As String)
            For n = 0 To str.Length - 1
                If IsNumeric(str.Substring(n, 1)) Then
                    Return n
                End If
            Next
            Return -1
        End Function
```

output will be: developerstreet

Answer (score 0):

```
text.Substring(0, text.IndexOfAny("0123456789"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.